# Connect two VirtualBox virtual machines through SSH

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox, suse

I have two VirtualBox virtual machines: one with SuSE Enterprise 10 and one with Red Hat Enterprise 5. I want to connect through SSH from RedHat to SuSE.

Both are configured to use a bridged adapter with `vnic0` as name and “Allow All” for “Promiscuous Mode”. SuSE has IP 10.211.55.5 and Red Hat has IP 10.211.55.6. I can connect through SSH from SuSE to Red Hat but not vice-versa. What could be the problem?

If I ping from Red Hat to SuSE and vice versa, everything is in order and the transmitted packets are received. If I traceroute from SuSE to Red Hat I get

```
1 10.211.55.6 (10.211.55.6)(H!) 0.509 ms (H!) 14.974 ms (H!) 0.877 ms
```

which seems in order, but when I traceroute from RedHat to SuSE I get

```
traceroute to 10.211.55.5 (10.211.55.5), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets
1 * * *
2 * * *
3 * * *
4 * * *
...
```

If I do `ssh -l user 10.211.55.6` from the SuSE virtual machine everything connects ok but if I do `ssh -l user 10.211.55.5` from the Red Hat virtual machine I get “Connection timed out”.

Both systems are connected to the internet and I can surf the net.
What am I doing wrong? Why I can't SSH from Red Hat to the SuSE virtual machine?

Comment: I think you need to configure gateway address on your RedHat.

Comment: Edit your question to show us the output of `ip ad` and `ip r` from both machines

Comment: A plausible reason is that the SuSE machine has a firewall that rejects incoming connections. Post the firewall configuration on both machines (`iptables -nvL`, and any other information you have on the firewall setup).

Comment: fiewall or there is no sshd running